# JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x91 - Rest Template Spring boot

Tags: json, spring-boot, unicode, jackson, resttemplate

This is a question that has been asked on Stackoverflow several times. But I could not found a solution for my specific scenario.
In all those cases, the solution is to save the json data in UTF-8; so that the caller gets a valid Json.

In my case with Spring boot and RestTemplate, I get a Json as a response for a API request I make to a third party server. I have no control whatsoever to change that side.

So, Is there any way that I can make **something from myside** as the receiving end to fix following issue.?

> JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x91

Below is how I have coded my request.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

----
----
 HttpEntity<HashMap> request = new HttpEntity(dataMap, headers);
```

Thank you..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it resolved.

I had to accept the response as a String first and then do the string manipulation accordingly as per the format I want the data to be.

```
String responseJsonString = restTemplate.postForObject(url, request, String.class);
```

Hope it might be of help for somebody.